# How can I access my home media from the internet?

Tags: windows-7, internet, streaming, media, dlna

At home all my media (audio, video, photos, etc...) are on an external drive.  This external drive is plugged into a router (which happens to have a USB slot) and is exposed to my home network via DLNA and Windows based Network Neighborhood.  At home I consume the media via a DLNA client (PS3, iPad, etc...).

How can I expose this media when I am outside the home network?  For instance, I'd like to listen to my audio collection while I am on the work Windows 7 computer?

Answer (score 4):

I recently installed [SubSonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) on my Amahi home server and opened it up to the world through a Proxy entry in my Apache servers.  You need a server to host the tool (its java based) and will need to open an appropriate router port to support it.
There is a nice web interface and mobile clients as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have some server on your network which is configured to accept requests from the Internet and serve you your files. One way to do this is with [Amahi Home Server](http://www.amahi.org/). This requires a dedicated PC, though it doesn't necessarily have to be a new or powerful one.